# bootstrap isn't working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have written a simple view to use bootstrap css in codeignitor.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Voyager</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
</head>
<body>

                <div class="panel panel-heading">
                    This is Heading
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("styles/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("styles/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>

</body>
</html>.
```

Bootstrap directory is copied in root directory of project.

This is the link I followed for integration.

http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/06/integrate-twitter-bootstrap3-with-codeigniter-framework.html

While running the application I get below error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: views/view_login.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:
```

**Note: If I remove bootstrap links, page is rendered without styles.**

Here is the contents of autoload.php.

I have excluded commented parts in this file.
I made changer to helper part as you said.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$autoload['packages'] = array();

$autoload['libraries'] = array();

$autoload['drivers'] = array();


$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

$autoload['config'] = array();

$autoload['language'] = array();

$autoload['model'] = array();
```

After this change new error I am getting is :

**Unable to load the requested file: helpers/view_login_helper.php**

Comment: If you remove base_url(), everything works. Bootstrap has nothing to do with it. Have you loaded the url helper?

Comment: You need to load ```url``` helper

Comment: I am new to CodeIgniter. Can you help me with how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your config/autoload.php and, in the helpers array do:

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

That should solve the problem.

EXTRA ADVICE: It's usually not necessary to protect a view from direct access. That's for your classes mainly. But still you can if you want to.

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('view_login'); Is this correct? where view_login is my view

Comment: No no, just write  `url`. You don't have to put any actual url there. What this does is that activates the `base_url()` function, that will help you load your files.

Comment: Now I am getting error: Unable to load the requested file: helpers/view_login_helper.php

Comment: That's because you still have this: `$autoload['helper'] = array('view_login');`. Change it to this `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` and it will work.

Comment: No. It isn't. I have removed that

Comment: You removed it or you changed it? Also, is your html file still he same way you posted here? What error throws? The same one?

Comment: I changed it. This is the error: Unable to load the requested file: helpers/view_login_helper.php

Comment: There' s something you're doing wrong. It throws that error because somewhere you are loading a view_login_helper.php that, of course, doesn't exists. Check the file and line of the error, and fix it.

Comment: I did as you said. still same error I am getting :(

Comment: Can you post the full contents of your config/autoload.php file?

Comment: Great, were getting closer. The error that throws: what line and file points to?

Comment: on line no 10 - Where head tag is closed.

Comment: So issue was that I was still loading helper from controller. removing that got it work, but still bootstrap is not applied. any guesses??

Comment: Check your config/config.php file, and make sure that `$config[base_url]` is set up correctly. You must end it with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Add url in  application\config\autoload.php 
In helper array

Answer (score 0):

Or you have to load this in the controller

Try to open your controller and load the view

```
$this->load->view('name of the view');
```